# MVC 4 Websecurity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Hello I am starting an mvc 4 site.

I need to add security to the site.

So far i have used the websecutiy class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity(v=vs.111).aspx

I have read though on here that the webmatrix security class has some limitations as compared to  System.Web.Security.Membership

I want the greatest flexibility in the future.

I also want one database that is created with the code first approach. I have achieved this with webmatrix security with WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection.

If i am using the default System.Web.Security.Membership how do i go about do this with code first. I would like the database in one place. I presume i need these config setting added.

```
<clear/>

<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"

     type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"

     connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"

     enablePasswordRetrieval="false"

     enablePasswordReset="true"

     requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"

     requiresUniqueEmail="false"

     passwordFormat="Hashed"

     maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"

     minRequiredPasswordLength="6"

     minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"

     passwordAttemptWindow="10"

     passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""

     applicationName="/"

        />
```

What are the advantages of using webmatrix security over system.web.security.

I am really stuck so you help would be great